# How to install php-cli on a docker image?

Tags: php, docker, glpi

I'm creating a custom docker image. I want to configure the image for the GLPI system. I have already installed some PHP extensions. I want to install the php-cli extension now.

There are php-cli docker images, but they do not contain the Apache server. I want to create an image with Apache and the necessary PHP extensions. Can you help me ?

Dockerfile used so far:

```
FROM php:8.3.2-apache-bookworm

# Definition of variables
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=America/Sao_Paulo \
    LANG=pt_BR.utf8 \
    LANGUAGE=pt_BR:pt \
    LC_ALL=pt_BR.UTF-8 

# Timezone and locales configuration
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && localedef -i pt_BR -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias $LC_ALL

# Installing additional packages
RUN apt-get install -y wget nano iproute2 iputils-ping

# Installing libraries required to install additional PHP extensions
RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev libldap2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev \
libsnmp-dev libzip-dev libpng-dev libonig-dev libbz2-dev libjpeg-dev libxml2-dev libfreetype6-dev

# Installing additional extensions - Docker Script
RUN docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install bz2 curl exif gd ldap imap intl mbstring mysqli opcache soap snmp xml zip

# Installing additional extensions - Pecl Command
RUN pecl install apcu \
    && pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/xmlrpc-1.0.0RC3  xmlrpc \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apcu xmlrpc

# Downloads the specified GLPI Version and unzips it to the web directory
RUN wget -O- https://github.com/glpi-project/glpi/releases/download/10.0.11/glpi-10.0.11.tgz | tar -zxv --strip-components=1 -C /var/www/html/ \
    && chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html \
    && find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; \
    && find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; \
    && apt-get purge -y wget


# Disable the default website and enable the GLPI website and required Apache modules
COPY glpi.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/glpi.conf
RUN a2dissite 000-default.conf \
    && a2ensite glpi.conf \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && a2enmod headers


# Clean up downloaded packages, remove no longer used dependencies, and remove package lists
RUN apt-get clean \
    && apt-get autoremove \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create the container with the user www-data
USER www-data
```

Comment: Did you try to add “apt-get install -y php-cli”?

Comment: `apt-get update && apt-get install -y php-cli`

**Output end:**

php8.2-cli 8.2.7-1~deb12u1 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'php-cli' has no installation candidate.

According to the official image documentation, you must use the commands: `docker-php-ext-install package` or `pecl install package`. However, I cannot install php-cli using these tools.

Comment: `php-cli` is not an extension, it's a completely separate binary to use PHP on the CLI. Additionally, the PHP docker images do not install PHP or extensions via any package management system, but compile them in-image. If you were to install php-cli from apt/etc it would be a wholly different program. Why do you need CLI PHP in a docker image?

Comment: @Sammitch I'm adapting a php environment for docker. The following packages must be installed:

`apt-get install -y apache2 php`
`apt-get -y install php-{cli,imap,ldap,xmlrpc,soap,curl,snmp,zip,apcu,gd,mbstring,mysql,xml,bz2,intl}`

See the dockerfile above. I have already installed most of the extensions.

Comment: I believe php-cli is optional for the GLPI system. However, I wanted to install it to have a complete environment. Note that I installed the extensions following the official image documentation.

Comment: If you truly need the CLI binary in the image you can reference the dockerfile on how to compile it. https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/8.3/bookworm/cli/Dockerfile